# how to add one to integer on submit button to jsp string?

Tags: java, jsp

```
<input type="text" name="integer" value="0"/>
<input type="submit" value="add one" />
```

---

```
<% 
String integer = request.getParameter("integer"); 
%>

<%
int x = 0;
try { x = Integer.parseInt("integer"); }
catch (Exception e) { x = 0; }
%>
```

How can I add one to the integer each time I hit the submit button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% 
String integer = request.getParameter("integer"); 
int x = (integer == null ? 0 : (Integer.parseInt(integer) + 1));
%>

<input type="text" name="integer" value="<%=x%>"/>
<input type="submit" value="add one" />
```